# Assigning a value to a bool

Tags: c++

OK, appologies in advance.  This is probably going to be a stupid question.

So have a simple class, eg something like

```
class Bullets : public RenderEvent
{
public:
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    Bullets();

    Bullets(Vector3D position, Vector3D direction);
    /**
     * Destructor
     */
                        ~Bullets();
    /**
     * Sets up the model and sets the bullets id
     */
    void                CreateBullet();
    /**
     * Renders the bullet if it is active
     */
    virtual void        Render();
    /**
     * Updates the movement of the bullet and detects if it has hit any characters
     * if it is still active
     */
    void                Update(
                            float elapsedTime
                            );
    /**
     * Sets the position of the bullet
     */ 
    void                SetPosition(
                            const Vector3D& pos
                            );
    /**
     * Gets current position of the bullet
     */
    const Vector3D&     GetPosition() const;
    /**
     * Sets the current rotation of the bullet
     */
    void                SetRotation(
                            const Vector3D& rot
                            );
    /**
     * Gets the current rotation of the bullet
     */
    const Vector3D&     GetRotation() const;
    /**
     * Sets the direction the bullet should move
     */
    void                SetForward(
                            const Vector3D& forward
                            );
    /**
     * Gets the direction of the bullet
     */
    const Vector3D&     GetForward() const;
    /**
     * Sets the bullet active
     */
    void                SetAlive(
                            bool alive
                            );
    /**
     * Returns if the bullet is currently active
     */
    bool                GetAlive() const;

private:

    MyString m_ID; 
  Model* m_model;

    Vector3D m_position;
    Vector3D m_rotation;
    Vector3D m_forward;
    float m_lifePeriod;

    bool m_alive;


    };

    #endif //_BULLET_H_
```

bullet.cpp

```
const float BULLETROTATIONTIME = 2.f;
const float BULLETSPEED = 30.0f;
const float LIFETIME = 1.0f;
const MyString BULLETMODELPATH = "Assets\\Models\\HARPOON_BOLT_01.x";


/************************************************************************/

Bullets::Bullets()
{
    m_position = Vector3D(0,2,0);
    m_rotation = Vector3D(0,0,0);
    m_forward = Vector3D(0,0,1);
    m_lifePeriod = LIFETIME;
    m_alive = true;
    m_flags = NoEffects;

  CreateBullet();
}

Bullets::Bullets(Vector3D position, Vector3D direction)
{
  m_position = position;
  m_rotation = Vector3D(0,0,0);
  m_forward = direction;
  m_lifePeriod = LIFETIME;
  m_alive = true;
  m_flags = NoEffects;

  CreateBullet();
}

/************************************************************************/

Bullets::~Bullets()
{
    RenderManager::GetInstance()->RemoveEvent(this);

  delete m_model;
}

/************************************************************************/

void
Bullets::CreateBullet()
{
    m_model = new Model(BULLETMODELPATH, m_position, m_rotation, 2.0f);

    RenderManager::GetInstance()->AddEvent(this, NULL);
  m_alive = true;
}

/************************************************************************/

void
Bullets::Render()
{
  m_alive = true;
    if(m_alive)
    {
        m_model->Render();
    }
}

/************************************************************************/

void
Bullets::Update(float elapsedTime)
{
    if(m_alive)
    {

    }

}

/************************************************************************/

void
Bullets::SetPosition(const Vector3D& pos)
{
    m_model->SetPosition(pos);
}

/************************************************************************/

const Vector3D&
Bullets::GetPosition() const
{
    return m_model->GetPosition();
}

/************************************************************************/

void
Bullets::SetRotation(const Vector3D& rot)
{
    m_model->SetRotation(rot);
}

/************************************************************************/

const Vector3D&
Bullets::GetRotation() const
{
    return m_model->GetRotation();
}

/************************************************************************/

void
Bullets::SetForward(const Vector3D& forward)
{
    m_forward = forward;
}

/************************************************************************/

const Vector3D&
Bullets::GetForward() const
{
    return m_forward;
}

/************************************************************************/

void
Bullets::SetAlive(bool alive)
{
    m_alive = alive;
}

/************************************************************************/

bool
Bullets::GetAlive() const
{
    return m_alive;
}

/************************************************************************/
```

OK, So my issue is that when the constructor is called or when in any other function, I can't change the value of `m_alive`...  it ALWAYS evaluates to `false`

and I don't seem to be able to change the value of the bool `m_alive` anywhere in the class in any function.

I'm not a beginner programmer but am feeling pretty stupid to why I can't change the value of a simple bool....

what could be interfering?

UPDATE:
So I did fix it (thanks @user007)  cleaning and rebuild fixed it.  But why?  If anyone could explain why I couldn't change the value of a variable until I had 'cleaned' the project?

Also, now that the answer has been found I would be nice if the question hadn't received so much -ve... (and that it wasn't put on hold)

Comment: Your evaluation logic is buggy.

Comment: How are you changing it? How are you check that it's false?

Comment: You have two constructors there. Are you calling the right one?

Comment: just trying to assign it to `true`.  Its like the member variable is const (but it obviously isn't)

Comment: @PSkocik  Yeah both have pretty much the same contents  (just one gives a default hard coded starting position/direction.

Comment: @unknownSPY. One thing I've learned is that there is very seldom black magic going on. What compiler are you using. Your probably doing something like this:
bool m_alive = true;

Also, please post the original code.

Comment: @Borgleader  its checked by using break points  before and after the attempt to assign it the value of "true"  and at both breakpoints (beginning of constructor and end) the debugger is telling me `m_alive == false`  even right after the line `m_alive = true;`

Comment: If your compiler supports C++11, you could use member initialization and write `bool m_alive = true;` in the class declaration.

Comment: using visual studio 2010

Comment: Clean Project and Build again maybe .. :P

Comment: Please try to set a breakpoint at the first non-blank line **immediately following** the line that sets `m_alive` to true and check the value hovering the mouse over `m_alive`. It should definitely read `true`.

Comment: 'It's not quite as simple as that', seems quite likely the problem is in the difference between what you posted and the real code.

Comment: @Banex  I have done exactly that and `m_alive` is being shown as ==false at both breakpoints.

Comment: You need to provide the code that **proves** what you are saying is really happening. All we can say from the code you provided is that assignments work. You need to show why that's not the case in your code.

Comment: Added the full code.

Comment: OK I have fixed the Issue and added the fix to the question. If anyone could explain why this happened that would be appreciated

Comment: @Galik I don't suppose you can explain why the fix worked and why it didn't work before.

Comment: Likely, for some reason, the object files the project was linking against didn't get updated when you "rebuilt" (or thought you were rebuilding). This sort of thing can happen a variety of ways, namely if the system clock gets changed and the IDE thinks all the source files are up to date even if they're not.

Comment: @cmbasnett hmm ok thanks.  Would have been nice if this question hadn't received such a negative rating. And in response to Galik's last comment I did add the full code and did prove what I was saying was true, not that it helped me or helped reduce the such negative rating this question got.

Answer (score 4):

From the looks of it, you're probably constructing your `Bullet` class with the "wrong" constructor, bypassing the assignment of `m_alive`.

There's a couple ways to solve it:

```
Bullet::Bullet() :
    m_alive(true)
{
}

Bullet::Bullet(Vector3 startingPosition, Vector3 direction) :
    Bullet() // calls default constructor (sets m_alive to true, always!)
{
}
```

Alternatively, you can just set the default value in the class definition (assuming your version of C++ supports this):

```
private:
    bool m_alive = true;
```

Comment: Sorry but both constructors contain `m_alive = true`;  And I am not using the wrong constructor,  I can use breakpoints to confirm this

Comment: Are you debugging in Release mode?

Comment: @unknownSPY Better provide an MCVE.

Comment: @cmbasnett no I am in debug

Comment: @unknownSPY PSkocik is right, you should provide a MCVE, otherwise it's anyone's guess.

Comment: @PSkocik what is MCVE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, I recommend using ideone.com

Comment: @cmbasnett  I have added the exact code now, I don't know what else I can add.

Comment: OK I have fixed the Issue and added the fix to the question. If anyone could explain why this happened that would be appreciated

Comment: @cmbasnett I don't suppose you can explain why the fix worked and why it didn't work before.